# React Testing Library render does not work with react router dom Navigate

Tags: jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a component which has a "Navigate" component inside it. I want to test this navigation. But whenever I try to render the component, the test case gets stuck and keeps on running forever.

I am using react-router-dom v6.

This is my sample code snippet.

```
render(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
    <Navigate to="/target" />
  </MemoryRouter>,
);
```

I have tried both `mount` method from enzyme and `render` method from RTL. This code snippet never produces any output. The test keep on executing forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test code is unconditionally rendering the `Navigate` component which issues a navigation action. This creates a render loop.

Place the `Navigate` component on a route so that it is ***conditionally*** rendered.

Example:

```
render(
  <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/target" />} />
    </Routes>
  </MemoryRouter>,
);
```

Above the `Navigate` component is rendered on the home `"/"` that is specified in the `MemoryRouter`'s `initialEntries` array prop value.